# How to change string to datetime format in android?

Tags: android

I am working on android project. I am setting date and time but it is displaying in the following format.

**Mon Nov 19 11:00:00 GMT+05:30 2012**

In my database table the datetime column datatype is **datetime**. So how can I change the above output to datetime format to store it in database.

Any help in this regard will be thankful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should probably read a bit about [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), it's the way to parse String into Date.

the way to do this is to create a pattern for the formatter, then create the formatter and after that parse the Strings.

```
String pattern = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date myDate = format.parse(str);
```